# How to handle 404 error in a async/await?

Tags: javascript, async-await

When fetching postcode from Postcode io API, I tried this error handling code:

```
async getCoord() {
    const postcodeAPI = `http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/dt12pbbbbbbbbb`;
    let response;
    try {
        response = await fetch(postcodeAPI);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    };
};
```

The `fetch` method returns a 404 error as postcode is invalid. In my understanding the try block should be tried and skipped and the error should be caught by the `catch` method, but instead I got this red 404 error in console:
[image]
which happens in the `try` block, and is the same as no error handling in the code. Why does this happen? Is it because this is browser default behaviour? Is there a way to improve the error handling here?

**EDIT**
What I wanted was the red console error to disappear and show my own error information instead, but the console error seems unavoidable.

Comment: Most browsers will show network request errors despite what error handling is in the code. In other words that will show up in your console no matter what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch API doesn't throw errors on any status code. It only throws errors on network failures, i.e. when it couldn't finish the request itself.

You can use `response.ok` to check if the request finished with `2XX` status code.

```js
async getCoord() {
    const postcodeAPI = `http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/dt12pbbbbbbbbb`;
    let response;
    try {
        response = await fetch(postcodeAPI);

        if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Request failed.');
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    };
};
```

You can also explicitly check the status code if you need:

```js
if (response.status === 404) {
    // handle 404
}
```

As for your question about logging `404` errors in the console, there's no way *or need* to avoid it. Whenever you make a request, it's being logged in the dev tools. But dev tools are just what they are called - tools for devs. You can safely assume your users won't look there and even if someone does, having `404` there is not the end of the world.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried your answer but still got the same 404 console error, what I meant was is there a way to avoid the red 404 error but logging it manually through the try catch?

Comment: The only way to avoid that error is not make these requests :) These errors are for information, don't take them as criticism.

Comment: i got it, so it is unavoidable, no problem.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to add that bit so I can accept it?

Comment: I added the answer as the last paragraph.