# Handle error 404 using openweather API and ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, openweathermap

I'm creating a very simple app who shows temperature of world cities.

I get error 404 when api returns `not found`.

I want to handle error 404 and showing a message saying something like `You have to introduce a valid city name`.

I tryied putting the following inside of `search` function (in the end) but does not work properly:

```
if (weather.cod){
   console.log("Erroooor");
}
```

This is my full code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const api = {
  key: "0e128f999e1fb1174d7af1d207406c01",
  base: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"
}

function App() {

  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});

  const search = evt => {
    if (evt.key === 'Enter') {
      fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            setWeather(result);
            setQuery('');
        });
    }
  }

  const dateBuilder = (d) => {
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]; 
    
    let day = days[d.getDay()];
    let date = d.getDate();
    let month = months[d.getMonth()];
    let year = [d.getFullYear()];

    return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`;
  }

  return (

    <div className={(typeof weather.main != "undefined")
      ? ((weather.main.temp > 20)
      ? 'app warm' : 'app cold') : 'app'}>
      <main>
        <div className="search-box">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="search-bar search-focus"
            placeholder="Type a city ..."
            onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
            value={query}
            onKeyPress={search}
          />
        </div>

        {(typeof weather.main != "undefined") ? (
          <div>
            <div className="location-box">
              <div className="location">{weather.name}, {weather.sys.country}</div>
              <div className="date">{dateBuilder(new Date())}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="weather-box">
              <div className="temp">
                {Math.round(weather.main.temp)}ºC
              </div>
              <div className="weather">
                {weather.weather[0].description}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : ('')}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You reeeeeeeeeally shouldn't post an API key on the internet.

Comment: maybe try/catch and throw new Error with that message if res.status === 404?

Comment: @sloont Oh, don't worry, is a test project, I don't care about the API. But thank you!

Comment: Anything anyone does with that key can be tied to whoever generated the key. I know you say its just a test project but still if someone does something malicious with it, its your key they're using to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can Add useState to handle error

Add

`const [notFoundError,setNotFoundError]= useState(false)`

in return, you can add if check to check if an error is true

```js
const App = ()=>{
const [notFoundError,setNotFoundError]= useState(false)
const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});

  const search = evt => {
    if (evt.key === 'Enter') {
      fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            // check if the API return the status 
            if(resuit.code == 404){
                  setNotFoundError(true)
            }else{
            // other status like 200
            
            setWeather(result);
            setQuery('');
            }
        });
    }
  }

return(
      notFoundError ? <h1>You have to introduce a valid city name</h1> :(
      <div> in case there is no error you can output the weather information </div>)
      );
}
```

**WARNING**: please remove and change your API key because it's a private thing and anyone can use this key, you should not share it on the internet

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** I think you have to try/catch still. So it would look cleaner to do `async/await` inside a `try/catch`. Here's a relevant [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63292240/how-to-handle-404-error-in-a-async-await). See the first answer.
I'm not great with jQuery so I can't help if any of that needs changed, but I don't think it does. You could throw a custom Error object when you get a 404.

Something like:

```
  const search = evt => {
    if (evt.key === 'Enter') {
      fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => {
           if (res.status === 404) {
             const error = new Error();
             error.message = 'You have to introduce a valid city name';
             throw error;
           }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            setWeather(result);
            setQuery('');
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
        
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can be possible that your code be syntaxically wrong? `Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)` exactly in the `.then` number 2: `.then(res => res.json())`

Comment: oh for sure, i didn't close any of the brackets before that. just edited

Comment: I appreaciate your help but now my browser console says that my `res` is undefined. And also `Cannot read property 'json' of undefined`

Comment: Is that after a 404? Does it run correctly with a 200?

Comment: edited answer with an explanation and a link to a solved SO post.